# In Microsoft Excel, need to pull information from on sheet to populate cells in other sheets, based of a id number search

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have one sheet in excel that I would like to enter an ID number "707442" and have excel go to another sheet and search the column that has the ID numbers.  When it finds the ID number I would like it to grab the information in the adjacent cell and bring it back to the first sheet to populate a different cell.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Look at VLOOKUP or the combination INDEX plus MATCH.  To refer to information on another sheet in the same workbook, include the other sheet name as part of the reference (in single quotes if the name contains any spaces), with an exclamation mark at the end of the sheet name, like 'sheet 2 name'!A1:B10.

Answer (score 1):

`VLOOKUP` should be the only formula you need for this. I've created a test sheet as so:

[image]

Then on Sheet2, I've put cell A1 as 707442, and B1 as the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A1:B4,2)
```

[image]

This looks at Cell A1 for what to look up. It uses range A1:B4 on Sheet1 as the data columns, always using the left-most column to search for the value (Column A in this case). If it finds it, it'll return the second column in the search range (Column B on Sheet1 in this case).